# Android Studio Keep saying Failed to complete Gradle execution

Tags: android, gradle

Everything fine with the command line

```
gradle build
```

But Android Studio keep saying that

```
Failed to complete Gradle execution
Cause:
A fatal exeption has occurred. Program will exit
```

If I clear all the cache, and restart everything will be fine, but this dialog will easily comeback again (after a build fail). I guess that the increment build chain is not good, but the message is not helpful at all.

Are there anythings I can do to get a more details message about what going on, why AndroidStudio Gradle failed? where can I put thing like `--stacktrace` in the Preferences of Android Studio?

Comment: Usually the Gradle console window will have more information.

Comment: I only saw the task list Executing tasks [:Newspaper:compileDebugJava] nothing more! is there way to activate log file of the gradle plugin?

Comment: Is there anything in the event log? Or the main log file (Help menu > Show log)? The latter one, especially, might have something. I don't think there's a way you can have it put something like --stacktrace (which probably won't help) or --info (which might help) on the command line it passes to Gradle from Android Studio builds.

Comment: "Could not run build action using Gradle installation 'D:\prg\Developper\gradle-1.10'" I donnot know why sometime Android Studio still tried to use 1.10, I already upgrade to AndroidStudio 0.5.8 with gradle 1.12. But it a good start that I know what is the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 23):

If you got a problem like this in Android studio, then don't worry about that, you are missing some thing which are here.

Go to **File-->Setting-->Gradle-->Gradle Vm Option**,
Now put this value ***-Xmx256m*** in the box, and hit the Apply button.

Here you have solved the problem.

Comment: I think it slows down your computer too may be because it is using less memory?

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67946
-XX:MaxHeapSize=256m -Xmx256m

Comment: Why it happens actually can you tell me?

Answer (score 1):

At my case, I forgot to include some jars at Libs folder at the Gradle file, actually I forgot to add ".jar" to the end of jar file name.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was not VM Option and Clean and Build did not work. My problem was that there were some images in **res folder** (so no grammatical errors) and Android Studio/IntelliJ return this error and saying nothing about images... **check all external data sources** in each file.